# VGG, perceptual loss in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a custom model to a loss function in keras. For example:

```
def model_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    inp = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))
    x = Dense(2)(inp)
    x = Flatten()(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[x])
    a = model(y_pred)
    b = model(y_true)

    # calculate MSE
    mse = K.mean(K.square(a - b))
    return mse
```

This is a simplified example. I'll actually be using a VGG net in the loss, so just trying to understand the mechanics of keras.

Comment: Have you tried it? It sounds simple to try. But I suggest to create the model outside the loss function. Your loss function should start in the line saying `a=model(y_pred)`.

Comment: But: do you expect that little model to be trained together with the model that contains the loss function?? Then I'd say no way.

Comment: no, it's a frozen model. this is for VGG loss

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way of doing that is appending your VGG to the end of your model, making sure all its layers have `trainable=False` before compiling.

Then you recalculate your Y_train.

Suppose you have these models:

```
mainModel - the one you want to apply a loss function    
lossModel - the one that is part of the loss function you want
```

Create a new model appending one to another:

```
from keras.models import Model

lossOut = lossModel(mainModel.output) #you pass the output of one model to the other

fullModel = Model(mainModel.input,lossOut) #you create a model for training following a certain path in the graph.
```

This model will have the exact same weights of mainModel and lossModel, and training this model will affect the other models.

Make sure lossModel is not trainable before compiling:

```
lossModel.trainable = False
for l in lossModel.layers:
    l.trainable = False

fullModel.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=....)
```

Now adjust your data for training:

```
fullYTrain = lossModel.predict(originalYTrain)
```

And finally do the training:

```
fullModel.fit(xTrain, fullYTrain, ....)
```

Comment: thanks. yeah, i saw this being done in other projects. is there a reason why this can't be added to the symbolic graph in the loss_fn? and operate on y_pred, y_true directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I'm going to answer it because no one did directly. You definitely can call another model in a custom loss, and I actually think it's much easier than adding the model to the end of your main model and creating a whole new one and a whole new set of training labels.

Here is an example that both calls a model and an outside function that we define -

```
def normalize_tensor(in_feat):
    norm_factor = tf.math.sqrt(tf.keras.backend.sum(in_feat**2, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
    return in_feat / (norm_factor + 1e-10)

def VGGLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    true = vgg(preprocess_input(y_true * 255))
    pred = vgg(preprocess_input(y_pred * 255))

    t = normalize_tensor(true[i])
    p = normalize_tensor(pred[i])
    vggLoss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(t - p))

    return vggLoss
```

vgg() just calls the vgg16 model with no head.
preprocess_input is a keras function that normalizes inputs to be used in the vgg model (here we are assuming your model outputs an image in 0-1 range, then we multiply by 255 to get 0-255 range for vgg).
normalize_tensor takes the vgg activations and makes them have a magnitude of 1 for each channel, otherwise your loss will be massive.