# Implement perceptual loss with pretrained VGG using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am relatively new to DL and Keras.

I am trying to implement perceptual loss using the pretrained VGG16 in Keras but have some troubles. I already found that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914931/vgg-perceptual-loss-in-keras) but I am still struggling :/

**A short explanation of what my network should do:**

I have a CNN (subsequent called mainModel) that gets grayscale images as input (#TrainData, 512, 512, 1) and outputs grayscale images with the same size. The network should reduce artifacts in the images - but I think it is not that important for this question. Instead of using e.g. MSE as loss function, I would like to implement the perceptual loss.

**What I want to do** (I hope I have properly understood the concept of perceptual loss):

I would like to append a lossModel (pretrained VGG16 with fixed params) to my mainModel. Then I would like to pass the output of the mainModel to the lossModel. In addition I pass the label images (Y_train) to the lossModel. Further on I compare the activations at a specific layer (e.g. block1_conv2) of the lossModel using e.g. MSE and use it as loss function.

**What I did so far:**

Load in data and create the mainModel:

```
### Load data ###
with h5py.File('.\train_test_val.h5', 'r') as hf:
    X_train = hf['X_train'][:]
    Y_train = hf['Y_train'][:]
    X_test = hf['X_test'][:]
    Y_test = hf['Y_test'][:]
    X_val = hf['X_val'][:]
    Y_val = hf['Y_val'][:]

### Create Main Model ###
input_1 = Input((512,512,9))
conv0 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), activation=relu, use_bias=True, padding='same')(input_1)
.
.
.

mainModel = Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=output)
```

Create lossModel, append it to mainModel and fix params:

```
### Create Loss Model (VGG16) ###
lossModel = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=mainModel.output, input_shape=(512,512, 1))
lossModel.trainable=False

for layer in lossModel.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
```

Create new model including both networks and compile it

```
### Create new Model ###
fullModel = Model(inputs=mainModel.input, outputs=lossModel.output)

fullModel.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse','mae'])
fullModel.summary()
```

Adjust label images by passing them through the lossNetwork:

```
Y_train_lossModel = lossModel.predict(Y_train)
```

Fit the fullModel using the perceptual loss:

```
fullModel.fit(X_train, Y_train_lossModel, batch_size=32, epochs=5, validation_data=[X_val,Y_val])
```

**Problems occurring:**

- VGG16 wants to get inputs of shape (?,?,**3**) but my mainModel outputs a grayscale image (?,?,**1**)
- Some issue with appending the lossModel to the mainModel

RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("conv2d_2/Relu:0", shape=(?, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

- How can I calculate the MSE at a specific layers activation and not at the output of the lossModel?

Thank you so much for your help and sorry for the extremely long question :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Number of channels

Well, the first problem is significant.

VGG models were made to color images with 3 channels... so, it's quite not the right model for your case. I'm not sure if there are models for black & white images, but you should search for them.

A workaround for that, which I don't know if will work well, is to make 3 copies  of `mainModel`'s output.

```
tripleOut = Concatenate()([mainModel.output,mainModel.output,mainModel.output])
```

### Graph disconnected

This means that nowhere in your code, you created a connection between the input and output of `fullModel`. You must connect the output of `mainModel` to the input of `lossModel`

But first, let's prepare the VGG model for multiple outputs.

### Preparing `lossModel` for multiple outputs

You must select which layers of the VGG model will be used to calculate the loss. If you use only the final output there won't be really a good perceptual loss because the final output is made more of concepts than of features.

So, after you select the layers, make a list of their indices or names:

```
selectedLayers = [1,2,9,10,17,18] #for instance
```

Let's make a new model from VGG16, but with multiple outputs:

```
#a list with the output tensors for each selected layer:
selectedOutputs = [lossModel.layers[i].output for i in selectedLayers]
     #or [lossModel.get_layer(name).output for name in selectedLayers]

#a new model that has multiple outputs:
lossModel = Model(lossModel.inputs,selectedOutputs)
```

## Joining the models

Now, here we create the connection between the two models.

We call the `lossModel` (as if it were a layer) taking the output of the `mainModel` as input:

```
lossModelOutputs = lossModel(tripleOut) #or mainModel.output if not using tripeOut
```

Now, with the graph entirely connected from the input of mainModel to the output of lossModel, we can create the fullModel:

```
fullModel = Model(mainModel.input, lossModelOutputs)

#if the line above doesn't work due to a type problem, make a list with lossModelOutputs:
lossModelOutputs = [lossModelOutputs[i] for i in range(len(selectedLayers))]
```

### Training

Take the predictions of this new `lossModel`, just as you did. But for the workaround, let's make it triple channel as well:

```
triple_Y_train = np.concatenate((Y_train,Y_train,Y_train),axis=-1)
Y_train_lossModel = lossModel.predict(triple_Y_train)
#the output will be a list of numpy arrays, one for each of the selected layers
```

Make sure you make each layer of `lossModel` non trainable before `fullModel.compile()`.

If you want 'mse' for all outputs, you just do:

```
fullModel.compile(loss='mse', ...)
```

If you want a different loss for each layer, pass a list of losses:

```
fullModel.compile(loss=[loss1,loss2,loss3,...], ...)
```

### Additional considerations

Since VGG is supposed to work with images in the caffe format, you might want to add a few layers after `mainModel` to make the output suitable. It's not absolutely required, but it would use the best performance from VGG.

See how keras transforms an input image ranging from 0 to 255 into a caffe format [here at line 15 or 44](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py/#L15)

Comment: Thank you very very much for the detailed and extremely helpful answer - **it works perfectly** . I wish it were possible to vote your answer more than once :) Thanks a million.

Comment: Instead of adding VGG as a new layer, how can I do it in custom loss function? I want to use VGG loss along with MSE loss. I want the model output to be image only. Loss function should take output image and target image, compute weighted average of MSE loss and VGG loss. I'm getting `TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor.` (I'm using tensorflow 2.0)